# Core-Plot inside a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, core-plot

I have a `UICollectionView` that has a Core-Plot graph inside of one of the cells.

I have no issues when making a Core-Plot graph in a `UIView`, but I'm having troubles getting this Core-Plot graph to work inside a `UICollectionViewCell`.

> In MyCollectionViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit
import CorePlot

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var corePlot: CPTGraphHostingView!
}
```

> In MyViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import CorePlot

class MyViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

...

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let theCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        let graph = CPTXYGraph(frame: theCell.corePlot.bounds)
        theCell.corePlot.hostedGraph = graph // This is where it crashes
        ...
    }

...

}
extension MyViewController: CPTScatterPlotDataSource, CPTScatterPlotDelegate {
    ...
}
```

> -[UIView setHostedGraph:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8a9aa20240
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setHostedGraph:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8a9aa20240'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set class name `CPTGraphHostingView` to `corePlot`

```
@IBOutlet weak var corePlot: CPTGraphHostingView!
```

Inside the xib file / prototype of cell in IB  , here `UIView` in crash

> [UIView setHostedGraph:]

means that you didn't assign it

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm new to Swift, so I don't have experience with xib files.

So you're saying that I should create a custom xib file, and add UIView as xib file’s owner, then add the view as an IBOutlet in UIView file.

Comment: Do you have a separate xib for the cell or a prototype cell above the collection inside IB ?? I mean where  you assign **MyCollectionViewCell** you should set class name for the aforementioned view

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand. When I created my cell, I did that in Storyboard. Then I populated the cell with a UIView. I connected the UIView as a CPTGraphHostingView in MyCollectionViewCell. Then in MyViewController, inside the cellForItemAt function, I tried to access it so I could create the graph.

Comment: select that view inside the cell , and set class name to it in identity inspector

Comment: Awesome. You're the GOAT.